# RSA Decryption - BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, private-key

I am writing RSA ENcyrption/Decryption.
Here's the code.
But when i decrypt using Private Key, I am getting exception

```
public class RSACrypto {

    private static SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

    /**
     * @param rsabits
     * @return keyPair
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static KeyPair newKeyPair(int rsabits) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(rsabits, sr);
        return generator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    /**
     * @param key
     * @return key
     */
    public static byte[] pubKeyToBytes(PublicKey key) {
        return key.getEncoded(); // X509 for a public key
    }

    /**
     * @param key
     * @return key
     */
    public static byte[] privKeyToBytes(PrivateKey key) {
        return key.getEncoded(); // PKCS8 for a private key
    }

    /**
     * @param bytes
     * @return key
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static PublicKey bytesToPubKey(byte[] bytes) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
    }

    /**
     * @param bytes
     * @return key
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static PrivateKey bytesToPrivKey(byte[] bytes) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
    }

    /**
     * @param input
     * @param key
     * @return encryptedText
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
     */
    public static byte[] encryptWithPubKey(byte[] input, PublicKey key) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(input);
    }

    /**
     * @param input
     * @param key
     * @return decryptedText
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
     */
    public static byte[] decryptWithPrivKey(byte[] input, PrivateKey key) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(input);
    }

    /**
     * @param plainText
     * @return encryptedText
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        KeyPair kp = newKeyPair(1 << 11); // 2048 bit RSA; might take a second to generate keys
        PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();
        PrivateKey priKey = kp.getPrivate();
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + new BASE64Encoder().encode(privKeyToBytes(priKey)));
        byte[] cipherText = encryptWithPubKey(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"), pubKey);
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherText);
    }

    /**
     * @param encrypted
     * @param privateKey
     * @return decryptedText
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
     */
    public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String privateKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        PrivateKey privateKeyValue = bytesToPrivKey(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(privateKey));
        return new String(decryptWithPrivKey(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encrypted), privateKeyValue), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

I am getting below error while **decrypting** with generated privateKey and encrypted text. I have gone through many posts, but couldn't figure what's going wrong here.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

Any idea, please help.

**Update**

I am calling from different class

```
String encryptedText = RSACrypto.encrypt("PLAIN TEXT"));

String privateKey = ""; //During encryption, it will print privatekey value, assigning the same here
String plaintext = RSACrypto.decrypt(encryptedText , privateKey);
```

After little work, I tried without encoding and decoding of Base64. it's working fine.

What I am messing up with base64 here? not getting any clue

Comment: Can you convert your code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think i already done the same. Simple code nothing to look much. While decryption i am getting error with the generated private key and encrypted text. no way to debug this and ended up seeking help. thanks

Comment: It's not clear how you use the various methods together. If you add a little `main` method into your supplied code, we can then execute that and see the same exception. *Then* we can help solve your problem.

Comment: 1) Consider using OAEP padding. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is broken. 2) Note that RSA can only encrypt short texts, so you probably need hybrid encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be making a mistake with your copy/paste. I edited your code to produce an (ugly) SSCCE that doesn't require copy paste. The methods that changed were:

```
public static StringPair encrypt(String plainText) 
    throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

  // Note: this is a very confusing way to say 2048
  KeyPair kp = newKeyPair(1 << 11); 

  PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();
  PrivateKey priKey = kp.getPrivate();
  byte[] cipherText = encryptWithPubKey(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"), pubKey);

  // Here I return both items, to remove copy/paste problems
  StringPair result = new StringPair();
  result.encryptedText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherText);
  result.key = new BASE64Encoder().encode(privKeyToBytes(priKey));
  return result;
}


private static class StringPair {
  public String encryptedText;
  public String key;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  StringPair result = RSACrypto.encrypt("PLAIN TEXT");    
  System.out.println(RSACrypto.decrypt(result.encryptedText, result.key));       
}
```

This prints `PLAIN TEXT`.